# How to fix "Could not find method" error?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm working on home work on Android studio, every thing was Ok, and I shut down my pc till next day, when i opened android studio i found this error message

> ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3' 
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

    // Displaying images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'

    // Realtime database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate Cache and Restart?

Comment: Maybe libraries you used need to update upper version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build file App Level :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.appname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//Add others below

}
```

Build file for Project Level :

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

After having the same as above, you perform clean and then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

This error because of Glide library:

add following dependency too with glide dependency:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

also if you are using **androidx** then you need to add :

```
annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
```

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `buildscript` dependencies are outdated; update them to the current version, then it will know about `implementation()` and `api()` - or just use previous `compile()`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}
```

That version number always equals the version number of Android Studio; eg. build-tools `3.4.1` requires Android Studio `3.4.1` to build... updating the whole installation should automatically fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I typed [compile()] instead of [implementation()] but i tried to update the gradle but when i sync it it doesnt work